# An ripe apple that has been cut and rice that are going to be cooked - correct?

Tags: nouns, relative-clauses

A relative clause is a clause that modifies a noun or noun phrase.

Can a relative clause modify a noun and a noun phrase at the same time?

**Example 1**

> An ripe apple that has been cut into pieces and rice **that are going to be cooked together** should be prepared right now

**that are going to be cooked together** is a relative clause.

**A ripe apple that has been cut into pieces** is a noun phrase.

**rice** is a noun only.

Can the relative clause modify **An apple I bought yesterday** and **rice** at the same time?

Comment: This is technically correct but needlessly complicated. Many readers will get lost in such a sentence.

Comment: @JeffreyCarney is correct. Because of the parallel structure (a ripe apple that ... and rice that ...) a reader is likely to think that the rice will be cooked together and the apple is cut into pieces.

Comment: **A chopped apple...** (Would you cook with an unripe one?)

Answer (score 3):

There is no rule that prevents this, but your specific example is so complicated that it would be considered *poor English*.

English, like every other natural language, has a recursive structure, for example a noun phrase can contain a clause that contains a noun phrase.  There is no rule for saying how deep and how complete this kind of structure can go.  But beyond a certain point, it becomes increasingly incomprehensible.  As an aim of good English is to communicate, pushing what is possible in grammar so it hard to understand is not a good idea.

A good principle to apply is is "end weight".  Place longer and weightier elements at the end of sentences.  A fault in your sentence is that it violates this principle by forming an overly long subject.

Applying those rules, and making a few minor modifications gives:

> You should now prepare a chopped apple and some rice that you will cook together.